# Grey Screen when launching Debian 6 through Chicken

Tags: ssh, terminal, debian, vps

I'm trying to connect my mac to my Debian 6 VPS, but I only get a gray screen, as shown in the screenshot below.

I followed the steps on [this tutorial](http://news.metaparadigma.de/linux-setting-up-a-debian-vnc-server-237/) recommended by the VPS company.

I'm using chicken (formally known as Chicken of VNC).

[image]